# MySQL multiple UNION with alias

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I've been looking at this for hours and I cannot spot the error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't2 UNION (SELECT a.item_id ' at line 34'

I've tried different variations of parenthesis and aliases, I've tried using `SELECT DISTINCT` with `UNION ALL`, I have verified the number of `?` parameters match... What am I missing?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT    a.item_id
      FROM      catalog_items AS a
      JOIN      catalog_franchises AS b ON a.game_id = b.franchise_id
      JOIN      catalog_franchises AS c ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id
      LEFT JOIN catalog_franchises AS d ON a.exclusive_id = d.franchise_id
      JOIN      catalog_item_categories AS e ON a.item_id = e.item_id
                AND e.valid = TRUE
      JOIN      catalog_categories AS f ON e.cat_id = f.cat_id AND f.parent_id = ?
                AND f.cat_id IN (?,?,?) AND f.valid = TRUE
      WHERE     d.franchise_id = ?
                AND a.valid = TRUE
                AND b.valid = TRUE
                AND c.valid = TRUE
                AND (d.valid = TRUE OR d.title IS NULL)
                AND a.region_id = ?
                AND a.quantity IS NOT NULL) t1
      UNION
     (SELECT    a.item_id
      FROM      catalog_items AS a
      JOIN      catalog_franchises AS b ON a.game_id = b.franchise_id
      JOIN      catalog_franchises AS c ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id
      LEFT JOIN catalog_franchises AS d ON a.exclusive_id = d.franchise_id
      JOIN      catalog_item_categories AS e ON a.item_id = e.item_id
                AND e.valid = TRUE
      JOIN      catalog_categories AS f ON e.cat_id = f.cat_id AND f.parent_id = ?
                AND f.cat_id IN (?,?) AND f.valid = TRUE
      WHERE     d.franchise_id = ?
                AND a.valid = TRUE
                AND b.valid = TRUE
                AND c.valid = TRUE
                AND (d.valid = TRUE OR d.title IS NULL)
                AND a.region_id = ?
                AND a.quantity IS NOT NULL) t2
      UNION
     (SELECT    a.item_id
      FROM      catalog_items AS a
      JOIN      catalog_franchises AS b ON a.game_id = b.franchise_id
      JOIN      catalog_franchises AS c ON a.manufacturer_id = c.franchise_id
      LEFT JOIN catalog_franchises AS d ON a.exclusive_id = d.franchise_id
      JOIN      catalog_editions AS e ON a.edition_id = e.edition_id AND e.edition_id IN (?,?,?) AND e.valid = TRUE
      WHERE     d.franchise_id = ?
                AND a.valid = TRUE
                AND b.valid = TRUE
                AND c.valid = TRUE
                AND (d.valid = TRUE OR d.title IS NULL)
                AND a.region_id = ?
                AND a.quantity IS NOT NULL) t3
```

Comment: you don't need to put alias when UNION multiple statements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what it should look like

```
select * from (
select ..
union
select...
) as x  -- you need alias here
```

what you did wrong is

```
select ... from
(
select ...
) as t1
union 
select ... -- then this prompted an error because the derived table just ended at the ')', anything after the 't1' is irrelevant
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: shouldn't this work:

select * from (
(select ..) as t1
union
(select...) as t2
) as x